# How to fix function that is copying unintentional rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm newer to JavaScript and have written a script that is intended to look in column A (labeled as "Status") for the status `Complete`, then cut the entire row out of that tab and paste it into another tab. There are four other statuses that can be selected via data validation including "New". This has been working fine until very recently when the script started also cutting rows with the "New" status as well. I'm not really sure what's going wrong at this point.

I've double checked the script to see if anyone has made any changes, and they haven't. I'm not exactly sure why it's selecting these "new" rows when it's not even mentioned in the script.

```
function ltToArchive() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('LT OQ');
  var dir = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('LT Archive');
  var rows = sheet.getMaxRows();
  var x = 1

  for ( x = 1; x <= rows; x++){
    var checkR = sheet.getRange(x, 1);
    var checkV = checkR.getValue();
    if ( checkV == 'Complete' ){
      var lastRow = dir.getLastRow();
      dir.insertRowAfter(lastRow);
      var dirRange = dir.getRange('A' + (lastRow+1) + ':Q' + (lastRow+1));
      var copyRange = sheet.getRange('A'+ x + ':Q' + x);

      copyRange.copyTo(dirRange);
      sheet.deleteRow(x);
    }
  }
  dir.sort(10,false);
}
```

Ideally, I want it to only select rows with `Complete`, no other rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
=query('LT OQ'!A:Q,"where A like 'Complete'")
```

might suit some with a similar problem.